Change session timeout based upon user type/group
I have a unique situation here.  In a site I am currently writing we need the session timeout to be 30 minutes if you are an admin and 1 hour if you are a regular user.  I can't seem to find any documentation in Laravel where you can change the session timeout based upon the user group or dynamically.  I am needing to change the timeout for the current session not all sessions.
In Dot Net it is as simple as:
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 60;
That only affects the current session.  So, it is easy to implement in code with if statement(s) to get the desired effect.  But unfortunately, this is not a Dot Net site.  It is a PHP Laravel site.
Thanks.

You can always update the configs at runtime like this config()->set('session.lifetime', $value); does that not work for you ?

Where do you load the config() for the session lifetime? can you provide a snippet of code?

.ENV has SESSION_LIFETIME set.  Within config/session.php it reads that value in and sets lifetime to that value.
